# US Urban Areas 15k+ in KML?

Tags: geospatial, us-census

Anyone know where I can get a KML of US urban areas with a population of 15k+?

Comment: not without doing some legwork. you can stitch that together from us census data

Comment: Doesn't geonames.org have something like this (for all cities over a given site and then reduce to just USA), or are you asking something different? Polygons?

Answer (score 3):

Have you see [Natural Earth Data Urban Areas](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-urban-area/)?  You can convert the .shp file to .kml with `ogr2ogr -f KML ne_10m_urban_areas.kml ne_10m_urban_areas.shp`.

Not sure about the population sizes that mark these as "urban" areas.